# Subconsulta no arroja lo que quiero

Tags: oracle

Una de las consideraciones para calcular el fondo de reserva que cada departamento debe pagar es la cantidad de dormitorios que posee. Por esta razón, se requiere contar con un cuadro resumen que por cada edificio que la empresa administra visualice el total de departamentos que posee y el total de departamentos que posee de acuerdo a la cantidad de dormitorios. Cabe señalar, que la empresa, por una política interna, administra edificios que poseen departamentos de hasta 5 dormitorios.
El usuario requiere que la información se muestre en el formato que se indica en el ejemplo y ordenada alfabéticamente por el nombre del edificio:

```
SELECT UPPER(E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO) AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
COUNT (D.ID_EDIFICIO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS" ,(SELECT COUNT(D.ID_EDIFICIO) 
FROM DEPARTAMENTO D WHERE  D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 1 ) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO" 
FROM EDIFICIO E JOIN DEPARTAMENTO D ON (E.ID_EDIFICIO = D.ID_EDIFICIO) 
GROUP BY E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO, D.ID_EDIFICIO;
```

Estoy haciendo el ejercicio solo con un dormitorio, ya que estoy aprendiendo y lo estoy haciendo por partes, pero al momento de realizar la consulta me cuanta en general y no por cada uno de los deptos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Examen duocUC compañero?

Answer (score 0):

La subconsulta que cuenta los departamentos de 1 habitación debe hacer referencia a la consulta principal, por ello siempre da el total.

```
SELECT UPPER(E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO) AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO", COUNT (D.ID_EDIFICIO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS"
,(SELECT COUNT(D.ID_EDIFICIO) FROM DEPARTAMENTO D WHERE D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = 1 and E.ID_EDIFICIO =D.ID_EDIFICIO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO"
FROM EDIFICIO E
JOIN DEPARTAMENTO D ON (E.ID_EDIFICIO = D.ID_EDIFICIO)
GROUP BY UPPER(E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta, resulta que ahora me tira un error en el group by, como dije anteriormente estoy aprendiendo todo esto y a veces me resulta un poco complicado.

Comment: @damian, siento el error, al mostrar solo una columna sin agregaciones, en el group by solo debe haber esa columna, lo he rectificado en la respuesta.

Comment: estimado, muchisimas gracias, no sabe cuanto estuve tratando de resolver el problema, un abrazo.

Comment: a pesar de la correción. Me sigue dando error en el group by. Alguna solución? estoy haciendo el mismo ejercicio.

Comment: Cada servidor de BD tiene sus diferencias en el leguaje SQL, prueba en el group by con `GROUP BY E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO);`, sin el 'UPPER'